# How do you take away the numbers next to the button in nop commerce

Tags: nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.90, nopcommerce-4.0, nopcommerce-3.80, nopcommerce-4.1

How do I take away the numbers next to my text it display the numbers of products available next to the button text

I have already tried cant get it fixed

Comment: Not sure what you do want to achieve, please explain it in a brief.

Comment: Please added some code for more clarify your questions.
Into this not get clear idea.

Comment: Its all good i figure it out, had to changed it in Settings, All Settings, ProductNumber